# If add h5py attributes' values, why the size of the h5 file not changed?

Tags: python, h5py

For example, I created an h5 file with a dataset.
I then added one attribute to the dataset. Why the size of the file is not changed? Are attributes' storage automatically allocated when the dataset is created?

The following code will print: 2848 2848 0

```
with h5py.File('dump.h5', 'a') as fid:
    fid.create_dataset('data', data=np.zeros([10, 10]))
s1=os.path.getsize('dump.h5')
with h5py.File('dump.h5', 'a') as fid:
    fid['data'].attrs.modify('pi', np.string_("3.1415926"))
s2=os.path.getsize('dump.h5')
print(s1, s2, s2-s1)
```

Comment: This probably has to do with the way the h5df files are defined and compressed. If you add more than one attribute, the file size changes. Would make it easer to give a good answer, if the purpose of your question is known. Is it just out of curiosity or related to a problem you are facing?

Comment: HDF5 is a complicated file format designed for large amounts of data.  It is not tightly packed, so small addition like this may not change overall size.  There's lots of info out there on this format, including a wiki article.

Answer (score 2):

My answer expands on comments by @Homer512. Attributes were originally intended to save "small bits" of data (aka meta-data). Typically these are scalars (strings, ints, floats), but can be larger objects (for example, np.arrays). The HDF Group considers the maximum attribute size to be 64K bytes. Initially, attributes are stored in the object's header (called "compact storage"). Over time, The HDF Group added two new ways of storing "large" attributes (>64K bytes) to the HDF5 library: 1) dense attribute storage (added in version 1.8) or 2) as a separate dataset (using an object reference). Also, attribute-related performance slows as the number of attributes grows. Dense attribute storage can be used to improve performance in these situations.

All that said, most of the time you don't have to worry about the storage mechanism.

To demonstrate, I extended your example to show 2 different behaviors: 1) add more attributes to increase space required, and 2) creat a group with the empty 10x10 array as  an attribute (and didn't create the 10x10 dataset). Run the code below and you will see the file size increase when you do this.

```
h5_file = 'dump.h5'
with h5py.File(h5_file, 'w') as fid:
    fid.create_dataset('data', data=np.zeros([10, 10]))
s1=os.path.getsize(h5_file)
with h5py.File(h5_file, 'a') as fid:
    fid['data'].attrs.modify('pi', np.string_("3.1415926"))
s2=os.path.getsize(h5_file)
print(f'Sizes for {h5_file}:\n{s1}, {s2}, {s2-s1}\n')

h5_file = 'dump1.h5'
with h5py.File(h5_file, 'w') as fid:
    fid.create_dataset('data', data=np.zeros([10, 10]))
s1=os.path.getsize(h5_file)
attr_dict = {'Version': 3.0, 
             'Date created': '2022-03-02',
             'Description': 'Example with several attributes',
             'Creator': 'kcw78' }
with h5py.File(h5_file, 'a') as fid:
    for k,v in attr_dict.items():
        fid['data'].attrs[k] = v
s2=os.path.getsize(h5_file)
print(f'Sizes for {h5_file}:\n{s1}, {s2}, {s2-s1}\n')

h5_file = 'dump2.h5'
with h5py.File(h5_file, 'w') as fid:
    fid.create_group('group1')
s1=os.path.getsize(h5_file)
with h5py.File(h5_file, 'a') as fid:
    fid['group1'].attrs.modify('arr', np.zeros([10, 10]))
s2=os.path.getsize(h5_file)
print(f'Sizes for {h5_file}:\n{s1}, {s2}, {s2-s1}\n')
```

Output is:

```
Sizes for dump.h5:
2848, 2848, 0

Sizes for dump1.h5:
2848, 8992, 6144

Sizes for dump2.h5:
1832, 2776, 944
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [HDF5 specification](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/H5.format.html) you see that [attributes](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/H5.format.html#AttributeMessage) are stored in the [object header](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/H5.format.html#ObjectHeader) (until the header runs out of space and allocates a continuation block). So, presumably, your attribute was written into preallocated space. Try writing a larger attribute or many small ones until you cross a reasonable limit like 64 kiB and see if it changes then.

Also, space is allocated from an on-disk heap (or multiple heaps to be precise). So that also makes file size changes less direct.